# What is a good sequence length for an LSTM time series model?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Given a date frame (m,n) where each m is a time step and n is the number of features. What is a good number for sequence length for a non-language time-series LSTM. When the 2D matrix is converted to a 3D matrix of [Batch Size, Sequence Length, Features] is there some sort of rule of thumb for choosing the Sequence Length since features are constant and batch size is dependent on Sequence Length.

2D to 3D conversion function

```
def splitter(seql,traindf,ytrue):
  m,n = traindf.shape
  timestep = m
  X_Train = []
  Y_Train = []
  for i in range(seql,timestep):
    X_Train.append(traindf[i-seql:i])
    Y_Train.append(ytrue[i][0])
  X_Train,Y_Train = np.array(X_Train),np.array(Y_Train)
  return X_Train,Y_Train
```

The best option I can think of is to run hyper-param tuning on sequence length. It seems like the smaller the sequence length the better my results in testing, but the issue is with different values for sequence length I get a different sized testing matrix which makes comparing the significance of results between sequence length hypers difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Sequence length is usually hyper-parameter that you search for, however you can determine the relative bound of that search depending on what your temporal data is and your domain knowledge. If for instance you know from experience that sales from more than 7 days ago don't seem to predict current sales at all then you might cap your sequence length at 7. Also you should fix your test set so it doesn't differ with different sequence lengths. For example you might have 1000 examples all of which have the number of time steps of your upper bound. Then just have a your data loader return always return two tensors X -> (batch_size, seq_len, features), and Y -> (batch_size, n_targets).